# output is column and want it to be in a row

Tags: python-2.7

I have a column of numbers I got from some code I wrote and I would like to list them in a row. I didn't get this from a file. It's a output from a loop a coded. Here's the code.

```
ast = [3,1]
fgh = list(itertools.product(ast, repeat=3))
hij = [",".join(map(str, item)) for item in fgh]

my_list = [3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1]
n=3
gth =[",".join(str(number) for number in my_list[(i * n):(i * n + n)])
  for i in range(len(my_list) / n)]

for i in range(0, len(gth)-1):
for t in range(0, len(hij)-1):
  if gth[i] == hij[t]:
     print gth[i]
```

this is what i get when I print gth[i]

```
3,1,3
3,1,3
3,1,3
3,3,3
3,1,1
```

And would like it to look like this.

```
['3,1,3', '3,1,3', '3,1,3', '3,3,3', '3,1,1']
```

I know I posed a question like this last night but every answer I got they assumed it was either a DataFrame or from a file which was my fault forgot to mention type. It's type is a string. But when I try to list it I get this.

```
['3', ',', '1', ',', '3']
['3', ',', '1', ',', '3']
['3', ',', '1', ',', '3']
['3', ',', '1', ',', '3']
['3', ',', '3', ',', '3']
['3', ',', '1', ',', '1']
```

What am I doing wrong here? If you need me too post more of the code to help understand the question please comment below, I just didn't want to clutter the question. Thanks!

Comment: "It's a output from a loop a coded".. What do you mean by this? Is it printed?

Comment: I coded a loop then I printed the result

Comment: Would it help to put the loop in the question? I just didnt want to make it really cluttered.

Comment: You want to know what is wrong with code you couldn't bother to post; good luck with that.

Comment: Yes posting the loop would help understand the question.

Comment: Why don't you just append `gth[i]` to a list instead of printing it?

Comment: Make a list before the loop and then instead of `print gth[i]`, do yourList.append(gth[i])

Comment: I want it to be it's own list of strings so I can use Counter function on it

Comment: oh ok let me try that

Comment: I get this                                                                                                         `[3]`
`[3, 3]`
`[3, 3, 1]`
`[3, 3, 1, 1]`
`[3, 3, 1, 1, 1]`
`[3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3]`   but in a column form it's not letting me show that. but first code is on top then second etc..

Comment: I put the whole code in the question that might clear up some misunderstanding. Sorry for all the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using is list:

```
import itertools

lst = []

ast = [3,1]
fgh = list(itertools.product(ast, repeat=3))
hij = [",".join(map(str, item)) for item in fgh]

my_list = [3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1]
n=3
gth =[",".join(str(number) for number in my_list[(i * n):(i * n + n)])

for i in range(len(my_list) / n)]

for i in range(0, len(gth)-1):
    for t in range(0, len(hij)-1):
      if gth[i] == hij[t]:
         lst.append(gth[i])
```

Output:

```
>>> lst
['3,1,3', '3,1,3', '3,1,3', '3,1,3', '3,3,3', '3,1,1']
```

Comment: I was putting the print underneath the if statement it was messing everything up. I've actually tried this before. But kept getting a weird print out, little dumb mistakes. Thanks i really appreciate it. Got it all figured out